# Rails how to check what an sql query is producing

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

This query doesn't produce an error but I'm pretty sure `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM relationships.created_at)` isn't doing what it's meant to.

```
last_check = @user.last_check.to_i
@new_relationships = User.select('"rels_unordered".*')
                         .from("(#{@rels_unordered.to_sql}) AS rels_unordered")
                         .joins("
                    INNER JOIN  relationships
                    ON          rels_unordered.id = relationships.character_id
                    WHERE       EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM relationships.created_at) > #{last_check}
                    GROUP BY    relationships.created_at
                    ORDER BY    relationships.created_at DESC
                    ")
```

How do I check exactly what `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM relationships.created_at)` is producing? The server logs don't show it, they just repeat the query. (At least the logs do show that `#{last_check}` correctly produces a number like 1471364015, which is why I think the problem is with the epoch code.)

Answer (score 1):

I would just go to mysql and try it out:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM relationships.created_at) FROM relationships limit 0,1;
```

and see what kind of answer you get. Alter the above to specify a particular record if need be.

A larger problem may be the EPOCH parameter; I'm not sure it's valid. See the mySQL reference for [EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) and its [parameters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).